# Android sometimes restarts my React Native application in the background

Tags: react-native

I am creating a fitness application in `react-native 0.66.1`. To manage my pages, I use [react-navigation 6](https://reactnavigation.org/).

My cover page, HomeScreen, allows to load user data before actually entering the application :

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      // load user data and app configuration in context

      navigation.navigate('AppScreen')
    }, [])
  )

  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator />
      <Image ... logo />
    </View>
  )
}
```

On one of my pages (`StartGymScreen`), I have a countdown using the react-native library [react-native-countdown-circle-timer](https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer/tree/master/packages/mobile#readme).

Everything works fine but **sometimes** when I put the app in the background and come back to it, it fully recharges via `HomeScreen`. My countdown is therefore lost (I have to come back to `StartGymScreen` and restart it).

I think (but I'm not sure) that this is a normal situation and that "Android" sometimes turns off apps to conserve battery power.

But I have a few questions :

- I did not find anything on the [react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/), what explains this ?
- Is it possible to prevent this? Sometimes the application restarts after 1 minute of background. Sometimes 2, sometimes 3 ... it's very random.
- I sometimes use another fitness app ([Hercules](https://www.herculeapp.com/)) which also has a countdown timer but not this problem, how does it do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you said, this is normal behavior and not related to your application. The android os will handle these jobs for your applications.

There are some settings in the phone to limit your application from running in the background. But it's not the ideal way to manage this issue.

All your needs are to **keep running your application in the background**.

So, there are some solutions like using **headless Js**. read more on RN [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android). You can create an unstoppable service for your application. You can use [this](https://medium.com/reactbrasil/how-to-create-an-unstoppable-service-in-react-native-using-headless-js-93656b6fd5d1) article to do it.

Also, there is a solution with using `react-native-background-actions` [package](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions).